# Conditional if and else statement logic working but is it optimal?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm still new to PHP and wrote this if-else statement and it's working but I am not confident enough to put it online on my blog:

- If it's the homepage, show logo.png
- If it's not the homepage & if there's a thumbnail, show the thumbnail.
- If it's not the homepage & there's no thumbnail, show the logo.

Is my code correct and optimal?

```
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ ?>
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png">
      <?php } else if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()){ ?>
      <?php if( !empty(get_the_post_thumbnail()) ) { ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium_large'); ?>" />
        <?php } else { ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png">
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It is normal if else scenario,So don't worry about the delaty in checking the condition. If it was a looping case you can think about optimising

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine, as a good practice we must keep the word optimization in mind, if we think the same here the else if is not required we can write the same inside the else.

```
 <?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png">
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if (!empty(get_the_post_thumbnail())) { ?>
            <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium_large'); ?>" />
        <?php } else { ?>
            <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png">
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: For good practice, readability is more important IMHO

Comment: My code is more readable or @Pattatharasu Nataraj's code is more readable?

Comment: Both are readable, we have to look the following things to make the code readable

* using more meaningful variables, functions and classes
* proper consistent indentation of code and code formatting
* using comments
* Keeping the functions short
* keeping the logics straigt forward rather than using it clever

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only two different values you're switching between, you can do it in one single `if/else`.

I also added the value to a PHP variable instead of duplicating the HTML code inside the `if/else`'s. Imo, it helps with both readability and maintainability.

```php
<?php
$isHomeOrFront = is_home() || is_front_page();

if (!$isHomeOrFront && !empty(get_the_post_thumbnail())) {
    $ogImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium_large');
} else {
    $ogImage = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png';
}
?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $ogImage ?>">
```

An alternative would be to use a ternary operation instead of a `if/else`. It's up to personal preference.

```php
$ogImage = (!$isHomeOrFront && !empty(get_the_post_thumbnail()))
    ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium_large')
    : get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png';
```